# Using custom fields for image alt and title

Tags: plugins, php, functions

I've Add a custom field to my products editing page with ACF.
Custom field name is `my_seo_title` ;
Each product has a unique SEO Title.
How can I use this field as an alt text and title for images in frontend?

Answer (score 1):

You can use ACF function like this:

`<?php get_field('my_seo_title') ? the_field('my_seo_title') : echo ""; ?>`

inside `alt` tag or `title` tag at front-end.